# Why hyperconjugation can't stabilize carbanion?

Tags: stability, resonance, hyperconjugation

If Resonance can stabilize both carbo cation and anion then why can't hyperconjugation stabilize carbanion ? Since both Resonance and Hyperconjugation are pretty much the same, i.e both involve delocalisation or diffusion of electrons( at least in model) ?

Comment: Unfavourable geometry.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Hyperconjugation involves the electrons from an adjacent bond to "donate" electrons to an empty p orbital. Now if we consider a filled p orbital, or a carbo-anion, then there will be a repulsive force according to [Coulomb's law](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_ChemPRIME_(Moore_et_al.)/05The_Electronic_Structure_of_Atoms/5.09%3A_Coulomb%E2%80%99s_Law). This will destabilize the molecule in question. However, resonance involves the delocalization of electrons in a molecule; whether this stabilizes the molecule depends on what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1):

In carbanion the carbon carrying negative charge contains one $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybrid orbital which contains a pair of electrons and therefore there is no possibility that it will undergo bonding interaction with the neighbouring $\ce{C-H}$ bond, due to repulsion between the electrons.