The Reason Behind the Order of Carbanion Stability: Tertiary, Secondary, Primary, and Methyl Anions

I'm trying to understand why carbanion stability follows this order:
tertiary carbanion (least stable) < secondary carbanion (moderate stability) < primary carbanion (more stable) < methyl anion (most stable).
Most sources say this is due to the electron-donating nature (positive inductive effect) of alkyl groups attached to the carbanion. However, I don’t think that is true because the inductive effect operates only when there is a difference in electronegativity. I don't think the partial negative charge on the alpha carbons (the carbons directly attached to the carbon with the complete negative charge) would be donated to the carbon with the negative charge; because even from an electrostatic perspective, this doesn’t seem accurate.
Please see the image to understand which partial charge I am referring to.
Many answers I found online claim that this order is due to both the inductive effect and hyperconjugation. But hyperconjugation cannot operate here because, for it to occur, there must be an empty p orbital, a partially filled p orbital (as in the case of carbon radicals), or a π* molecular orbital (in the case of alkenes) to accept electron density from the C–H or C–C sigma bonds. However, that is not the case here since the orbital holding the negative charge is fully occupied (with two electrons, the maximum it can hold), so how would it accept more?
Thank you for reading my question till the end. It is a request, if possible, please provide an answer that explains the "why" and "how" behind this problem.
P.S.: I believe it’s neither the inductive effect of the alkyl groups nor hyperconjugation. Instead, it’s the Coulombic repulsion between the negative charge on the carbanion and the partial negative charges on the three carbons directly attached to it.

I feel like you're wasting time. Such ions hardly exist, much less are important for anything. Still, I think there was a lot of old questions about it already.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124623/why-hyperconjugation-cant-stabilize-carbanion https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135561/carbanion-stability-order

But I didn't find a proper duplicate, I think.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/154144/why-is-the-carbanion-stability-order-the-way-it-is-321

"Coulombic repulsion between the negative charge on the carbanion and the partial negative charges on the three carbons..." is that not just saying the same thing as the inductive effect being responsible? I don't see the confusion here.

Well @mithoron they kind of exist, for example when you look at the reactivity of tert-butyl lithium vs. n-butyl lithium.. it does make a difference

@Mäßige But neither got a real carbanion.

@Mithoron I’m not wasting time; why would I do that? I’ve read the answers to the possible duplicates, which is why I said, 'Many answers I found online' and explained the issues I encountered with them. I also outlined my reasons for why hyperconjugation shouldn’t apply in this case, nor the inductive effect.

@Sonder I'm sorry, sir; I'm not familiar with that. I would be grateful if you could explain it to me.

@Sauron The "electron releasing" natures of the methyl group have to do with the nonzero electronegativity difference between C and H, leading to C having a greater amount of the electron share from the bonds. The electron "releasing" nature is not something the carbon has a choice in—it just has electron density. So of course, when you have more of these electron dense carbons surrounding a negative charge, increased repulsion is implied. This disfavors the formation of a tertiary carbocation. It really is just an inductive effect.

@Sonder I now understand exactly what you are trying to say! Are you suggesting that the partial negative charges and the resulting repulsion between them and the negative charge on the negatively charged carbon are due to the inductive effect, which causes partial negative charges to develop on the attached carbons?
